# Why do you prefer char* instead of string, in C++?

Tags: c++, c, string

I'm a C programmer trying to write c++ code. I heard `string` in C++ was better than `char*` in terms of security, performance, etc, however sometimes it seems that `char*` is a better choice. Someone suggested that programmers should not use `char*` in C++ because we could do all things that `char*` could do with string, and it's more secure and faster.

Did you ever used `char*` in C++? What are the specific conditions?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

It's safer to use `std::string` because you don't need to worry about allocating / deallocating memory for the string.  The C++ `std::string` class is likely to use a `char*` array internally.  However, the class will manage the allocation, reallocation, and deallocation of the internal array for you.  This removes all the usual risks that come with using raw pointers, such as memory leaks, buffer overflows, etc.

Additionally, it's also incredibly convenient.  You can copy strings, append to a string, etc., without having to manually provide buffer space or use functions like strcpy/strcat.  With std::string it's as simple as using the `=` or `+` operators.

Basically, it's:

```
 std::string s1 = "Hello ";
 std::string s2 = s1 + "World";
```

versus...

```
 const char* s1 = "Hello";
 char s2[1024]; // How much should I really even allocate here?
 strcpy(s2, s1);
 strcat(s2, " World ");
```

**Edit:**

In response to your edit regarding the use of `char*` in C++: Many C++ programmers will claim you should *never* use `char*` unless you're working with some API/legacy function that requires it, in which case you can use the `std::string::c_str()` function to convert an `std::string` to `const char*`.

However, I would say there are some legitimate uses of C-arrays in C++.  For example, if performance is absolutely critical, a small C-array on the stack may be a better solution than `std::string`.  You may also be writing a program where you need absolute control over memory allocation/deallocation, in which case you would use `char*`.  Also, as was pointed out in the comments section, `std::string` isn't guaranteed to provide you with a contiguous, writable buffer *, so you can't directly write from a file into an `std::string` if you need your program to be completely portable.  However, in the event you need to do this, `std::vector` would still probably be preferable to using a raw C-array.

* Although in C++11 this has changed so that `std::string` does provide you with a contiguous buffer

Comment: At times, using string is harder though. Its trivial to turn a byte stream into a null terminated char *. It's not so trivial with std::string though

Comment: @earlz: I consider calling a function (`std::string::c_str()`) rather trivial.

Comment: std::string has a constructor for that.

Comment: That std::string makes it hard-to-impossible to get a writable buffer is an issue---you have to rely on implementation details (the question is interpreted both ways on whether the standard actually requires &s[0] to work as it does for vector), or mix another container (vectors or char arrays) with strings.

Comment: @Roger: that's actually a good point. Since std::string is not guaranteed to have a contiguous internal buffer, you can't safely do things like read directly into a string from a file.

Comment: The only valid reason to use `char *` as far as I have constated is when delivering an API to a client that may not have the same STL than you do :/

Comment: One simple reason to use char* instead of string is if you have to avoid dynamic memory allocation (i.e. perhaps in an interrupt handler or on an embedded system).

Comment: I think that all of the exceptions come down to, use char* if you know that you have to.  If you don't have a good reason (and most of the time you don't), use std::string.

Comment: Another specific instance to prefer char* over std::string is where you need a static string constant.  If have static std::string instances (in a cpp file or as static class members) then you may run into order-of-initialisation problems.  Using a raw char* avoids this problem.

Comment: @Adisak: If you have to avoid dynamic memory allocation, use a specialized allocator with your `std::string` to allocate memory on the stack.

Comment: @the_mandrill: If I have a static string constant, I use `const char[]`.

Comment: @Adisak most common `std::string` implementations use an internal char buffer to avoid memory allocations and chache-miss-prone indirections for little strings. Was that common when this answer was posted, or its a new idiom?

Comment: @MooingDuck - You can't wrap alloca() in other functions so making a specialized allocator for the stack to pass into std:string doesn't work.  Show me code if you know a way around this.

Comment: @Manu343726 - The static storage (internal char buffer) for strings in std::string is only for strings up to a certain (typically small) size.  Any larger strings require dynamic allocation.

Comment: @Adisak: Not alloca, use a memory pool.  MSVC comes with macros to generate custom memory pools, as does boost.

Comment: If you can absolutely 110% guarantee the string will not be longer than 128 bytes or so. It's almost always faster to use a stack char array. If you care about fine tuning your code, string manipulation is obviously faster in C also, because at the end of the day C++ implementations are for the performance critical parts, written in C.

Answer (score 6):

Ok, the question changed a lot since I first answered.

Native char arrays are a nightmare of memory management and buffer overruns compared to std::string.  I always prefer to use std::string.

That said, char array may be a better choice in some circumstances due to performance constraints (although std::string may actually be faster in some cases -- measure first!) or prohibition of dynamic memory usage in an embedded environment, etc.

Answer (score 2):

In general, std::string is a cleaner, safer way to go because it removes the burden of memory management from the programmer. The main reason it can be faster than char *'s, is that std::string stores the length of the string. So, you don't have to do the work of iterating through the entire character array looking for the terminating NULL character each time you want to do a copy, append, etc.

That being said, you will still find a lot of c++ programs that use a mix of std::string and char *, or have even written their own string classes from scratch. In older compilers, std::string was a memory hog and not necessarily as fast as it could be. This has gotten better over time, but some high-performance applications (e.g., games and servers) can still benefit from hand-tuned string manipulations and memory-management.

I would recommend starting out with std::string, or possibly creating a wrapper for it with more utility functions (e.g., starts_with(), split(), format(), etc.). If you find when benchmarking your code that string manipulation is a bottleneck, or uses too much memory, you can then decide if you want to accept the extra risks and testing that a custom string library demands.

*TIP: One way of getting around the memory issues and still use std::string is to use an embedded database such as [SQLite](http://www.hwaci.com/sw/sqlite/). This is particularly useful when generating and manipulating extremely large lists of strings, and performance is better than what you might expect.*

Answer (score 1):

C char * strings cannot contain '\0' characters. C++ string can handle null characters without a problem. If users enter strings containing \0 and you use C strings, your code may fail. There are also security issues associated with this.

Comment: In both C and C++, char * strings point to regular memory arrays. If you really want to, you can embed extra '\0' characters in them. A common performance trick when parsing things like file system paths is to temporarily "truncate" a string by swapping out characters with '\0'. Another common use it to represent a list of strings in a single array, using '\0' for delimiters with a double-NULL at the very end.

Comment: More correctly, the C string functions (strcpy, etc.) cannot handle '\0', since they use it as an end of string marker.  If you are willing to write your own fuctions, char* can contain '\0' just fine.

Comment: I've never seen anyone uses the character `'\0'`

Comment: C char strings are just pointers to raw memory. As for character '\0' I have seen it used in the case where you have multiple string in one area of memory. you end the multiple strings with two '\0'. Reason is that it saves memory compared to a list of multiple pointers. That's said, is rare to see.

Answer (score 1):

Implementations of `std::string` hide the memory usage from you.  If you're writing performance-critical code, or you actually have to worry about memory fragmentation, then using char* can save you a lot of headaches.

For anything else though, the fact that `std::string` hides all of this from you makes it so much more usable.

Answer (score 0):

String may actually be better in terms of performance. And innumerable other reasons - security, memory management, convenient string functions, make std::string an infinitely better choice.

Edit: To see why string might be more efficient, read Herb Sutter's books - he discusses a way to internally implement string to use Lazy Initialization combined with Referencing.

Comment: I'd +1 if you give more info on how strings are more efficient. Just a summary/conclusions, I can go get the book if I want the details.

Comment: I think he's referring to Copy-on-Write semantics, which, is actually a bad idea these days due to multi-threading.

Comment: If you are referring to copy-on-write, then time has proven worth and at the end it seems that copy-on-write will not improve performance over current early copy implementations. Copy-on-write has many problems with multithreading and the solutions require exclusive locks that have more costs than the gain that copy-on-write provides.

Comment: Some things that are more efficient: getting the size of a string is a constant time operation in std::string but linear time on the size of the string with const char*, and thereof any operation that requires calculating the size of the string

Comment: @Charles, Dribeas, Caspin - It *is* copy-on-write semantics I was referring to, and I see your point (though I'll have to weigh out the pros and cons). Thanks.

Comment: string holds the size on a size_t element, thus does not need to go trough the whole string to find its len. In this way is more efficient. However it does use constructor/destructor and always uses the heap. So sometimes the humble c string will be far more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Use `std::string` for its incredible convenience - automatic memory handling and methods / operators. With some string manipulations, most implementations will have optimizations in place (such as delayed evaluation of several subsequent manipulations - saves memory copying).

If you need to rely on the specific char layout in memory for other optimizations, try `std::vector<char>` instead. If you have a non-empty vector `vec`, you can get a `char*` pointer using `&vec[0]` (the vector has to be nonempty).

Comment: In this case, I'd also recommend explicitly wrapping string functions to handle a NULL delimiter - just setting a vector of chars does not delimit it.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, I don't. The exception is when I'm using third party libraries that require them. In those cases I try to stick to std::string::c_str().

Answer (score -1):

In all my professional career I've had an opportunity to use std::string at only two projects. All others had their own string classes :)

Having said that, for new code I generally use std::string when I can, except for module boundaries (functions exported by dlls/shared libraries) where I tend to expose C interface and stay away from C++ types and issues with binary incompatibilities between compilers and std library implementations.

Comment: Most libraries have been in development for a long time, and offer their own string function. Most of these (the well maintained ones at least) offer a way to convert to and from std::string. 

Even if they don't, using the c_str() function for std::string to convert to c-string at the interface point is probably a good idea. 

I'll go out on a limb and say, wrap every vendor API up in your own API - makes it easier to transition between libraries, and port away from obsolete libraries (read, those with no time to even code in support for std::string).

Answer (score -2):

Compare and contrast the following C and C++ examples:

```
strlen(infinitelengthstring)
```

versus

```
string.length()
```

Answer (score -2):

std::string is almost always preferred. Even for speed, it uses small array on the stack before dynamically allocating more for larger strings.

However, char* pointers are still needed in many situations for writing strings/data into a raw buffer (e.g. network I/O), which can't be done with std::string.

Comment: Your comment about `std::string` using small arrays on the stack is not necessarily true.  It's just an implementation detail that *some* implementors may use, not an inherent advantage to std::string

Answer (score -2):

The only time I've recently used a C-style char string in a C++ program was on a project that needed to make use of two C libraries that (of course) used C strings exclusively. Converting back and forth between the two string types made the code really convoluted.

I also had to do some manipulation on the strings that's actually kind of awkward to do with std::string, but I wouldn't have considered that a good reason to use C strings in the absence of the above constraint.