# How can i access individual elements of a string in an array of pointers?

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

main()
{
  char *p[4] = {"arp","naya","ajin","shub"};
  cout<<*p[2];    // How is this printing 'a' 
                  // how can i print the elements of each of the 4 strings 
                  // except the first character
```

}

Visit http://cpp.sh/7fjbo
I'm having a lot of problems in understanding handling of pointers with strings. If you can help with that, please post some additional links. Underastanding the use of arrays with pointers is my primary concern.

Comment: Fill it with different data so you can know which `char` it is printing..

Comment: If you do this only to practise pointers then it's ok, BUT I would like to point out that ISO C++ forbids conversion between string constant (and `"ajin"` is exactly that) and `char*` . You should use std::string if it's not only for learning purposes.

Answer (score 4):

p[2] is a pointer to the first element of `"ajin"`. When you dereference it, you get `a`. If you want to print all of it, use the pointer itself

```
cout << p[2];
```

If you want to skip the first characters, pass a pointer to the second character to cout, i.e.

```
cout << p[2] + 1;
```

Comment: You could also use `cout << p[2][1]` .

Comment: @Lehu: That would print only the second character. `p[2][1]` is equivalent to `*(p[2] + 1)`, not `p[2] + 1`

Comment: Sure, but he wanted to access individual characters :) . Ah! In the comments he wrote about skipping first character!

Answer (score 1):

Here, `p` is basically array of string pointers with array length 4.

`*p[2]` is same as `p[2][0]`

`p[2]` is same as "start from index `0` and print till the compiler finds `'\0'`"

`p[2] + i` is same as "start from index `i` and print till the compiler finds `'\0'`"

Comment: If it's C++ (and it is) I would write that p is array of `char**`. If I see "string pointer" mentioned then for me it's `string*` which is not the case here.

Answer (score 1):

Some more information in addition to Armen's answer to give you a better understanding.

C++ is *not* *exactly* C; it is a strongly typed language. In C, you use `char *` to denote a null-terminated string. But actually, it means **a pointer to the char type**. C++, being strongly typed, is invoking

```
std::ostream& std::ostream::operator<<(std::ostream& cout, char);
```

with

```
cout << *p[2];
```

since the second operand is of type `char`.

In C++, you may want to use `std::string` instead of `char*` because the former is safer and has an easier interface. For details, you can refer to [Why do you prefer char* instead of string, in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1764079/why-do-you-prefer-char-instead-of-string-in-c)